# Syntax error when trying to run server.py through command prompt

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-sockets, python-webbrowser, python-server-pages

This is the code i am trying to run

```
import socket               


s = socket.socket()         
print ("Socket successfully created")

port = 12345                

s.bind(('', port))        
print ("socket binded to %s" %(port))

s.listen(5)     
print ("socket is listening")


while True:
   c, addr = s.accept()     
   print ('Got connection from', addr)
   c.send('Thank you for connecting')
   c.close()
```

[image: OUTPUT]
This code is running successfully, but the problem occurs when i try to run these commands:

```
# start the server
$ python server.py
# keep the above terminal open
# now open another terminal and type:
$ telnet localhost 12345
```

Error that is coming:
[image: Error: Invalid syntax]

When i type `$ python server.py` I am getting the same error.
A possible solution to this would have been that i didnt set my environment variable right, but when i type python in the command prompt, i get no error.
What I am doing wrong?

I copied this code from [Here (Python socket network programming)](https://pythontips.com/2013/08/06/python-socket-network-programming/)
PS: I am using 3.4.3 version

Comment: You're running it in the python shell. You need to run it in just a cmd window.

Comment: run `python server.py` from terminal not from `python shell`

Comment: Just like the error says, `$python ...` is invalid python syntax.

Comment: Please don't show pictures of code. Take the time to properly cut, paste, and format the information.

Comment: Also, you don't need the `$` sign.

Comment: try python /path/to/file

Comment: @BryanOakley Error i am getting now : `python: can't open file 'server.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` Can you please tell me what is going wrong now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it's telling you "no such file or directory" it means exactly that -- you're telling it to run "server.py" but "server.py" doesn't exist in the current directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python files have to run from the command prompt not from the shell

Syntax for running python files is

```
python "full path of python_file.py"
```

Comment: Error i am getting now : `python: can't open file 'server.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`. Can you please tell me what is going wrong now.

Comment: @sajal Did you enter full path of python file ?

Comment: Your answer is slightly incorrect. You do not have to give the full path of the python file. Relative paths work just fine.

Comment: Yes but since the file is not in current directory we need to input full path

Comment: So first i need to create a file named `server.py` ? I am sorry but i am really new to this all.

Comment: @Sajal if you haven't then how do you expect python to find server.py

Comment: @Agile_Eagle Okay, now I typed in the terminal, python `C:/Users/Sajal Sirohi.DESKTOP-RTVGPUA/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/scratches/server.py` _after creating the file server.py_ .. But it still is not working.. And the same error is coming. `python: can't open file 'C:/Users/Sajal': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Sajal add everything in double quotes then if it still does not work, add python before it

Comment: @Agile_Eagle Okay thank you so much for helping and being patient with noobs like me. Thanks once again.